# How to put two commas in a float?

Tags: c++, numbers

Im working on a college project and it requires big number like 43,000,000 but everytime i launch the program it gives me something like this 43000,000. I already used std::fixed and precision but it doesnt add the second comma.

this is the code:

```
double PreEnCol() {
    if (marca == 1)
        return (105.000*562);
    else if (marca == 2)
        return (65.000*562);
    else if (marca == 3) 
        return (54.000*562);
    else if (marca == 4) 
        return (125.000*562);
    else if (marca == 5)
        return (129.000*562);
    else if (marca == 6)
        return (85.900*562);
}

string toString(){
    stringstream s;
    s << endl;
    s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << "Precio en colones: "<<PreEnCol() << endl;
    return s.str();
}
```

Please i need help with this i've been dealing with this problem for hours.

Comment: Try using C++ locales.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually do that [with default system locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale):

```
#include <locale>

string toString(){
    stringstream s;
    s << endl;
    s.imbue(std::locale(""));   // <-- set locale. OR: std::locale("en_US")
    s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << "Precio en colones: "<<PreEnCol() << endl;
    return s.str();
}
```

Note that this will print `43000000` as `43,000,000` in some parts of the world, or as `43.000.000` in others where `'.'` is used as grouping separator.

### [Here's full example](https://ideone.com/2R5xLJ):

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string toString(int n)
{
    stringstream s;
    s << endl;
    s.imbue(std::locale(""));   // <-- set locale
    s << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << "Precio en colones: "<< n << endl;
    return s.str();
}

int main()
{
    int n = 43000000;
    cout << "formatted " << n << ": " << toString(n) << endl;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
formatted 43000000: 
Precio en colones: 43,000,000
```

Comment: Beats the hell out of my plan: Root beer, vanilla ice cream, and a writer's handbook.

Comment: i put in my string toString code and it crashes, apparently it only crashes when "s.imbue(std::locale("")); " is in the code.

Comment: @juancaaaful what compiler do you use? Do you mean crashes at runtime or it fails to compile it? Don't forget that you need to add `#include <locale>`

Comment: i used #include <local> and my program start normally but when it shows the number the program crashes. It says "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'.

Comment: i found something else about my error: locale:: facet:: _S_create_c_locale not valid/ Im using #include <locale>

Comment: @juancaaaful as a random guess, try to `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`? and then re-run example code?

Comment: I don't know if this affects anything but i live in Costa Rica and for some reason when i this use program i found around here :               
                                                                                                         using namespace std;
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
 cout << "LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << endl;
 cout << "LC_CTYPE: " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << endl;
 return 0;
}                                                                                                                                   
   It says Spain

Comment: @juancaaaful it's because it's Spanish that's why it shows it as Spain

Comment: oh ok, so the export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 will stil work? and how should i do it?

Comment: Before running your test program execute this in terminal window: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, try also `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` and see if the program produces different output. If it still crashes, then try to change `std::locale("")` to `std::locale("en_US")` inside code

Answer (score 1):

Mostly your output depend on your default locale. You need to override you whole locale OR part of locale of you interest.

Below code helps you to override part of locale which is responsible for printing commas in number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
struct Sep3Digit : std::numpunct<char> {
    std::string do_grouping() const { return "\003"; }
};
std::string FormatWithCommas(double d)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new Sep3Digit));
    ss << std::fixed << d;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<FormatWithCommas(std::numeric_limits<double>::max())<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```